# Component drawing error React App on Android + Chrome

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome

The application generates incorrectly on Android with Chrome.
I am using realme 8i with Android 12 and the same problem is on the BrowserStack on realme 8 with Android 11. Do you know what is the cause?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOohh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzeHb.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.